# Print cycle in bash

Tags: bash

How to print this in bash, please?

```
for file in *.b; do
  a="$(awk 'NR==2{print $1}' "$file")"
  printf ('python2 script.py' $file '1 5.732436' $a "f$file" 'n')
done
```

I would like to print string 'python2 script.py', name of file, strings '1 5.732436' value of variable a, name of file and f in front of and string n.

The desired output (for directory with files: file1.b, file2.b, file3.b:

```
python2 script.py file1.b 1 5.732436 5.5 ffile1.b n
python2 script.py file2.b 1 5.732436 3.2 ffile2.b n
python2 script.py file3.b 1 5.732436 1.2 ffile3.b n
```

Comment: may be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/572863/4778 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/572904/4778 If not then use titles that explain what the question is about.

Comment: What are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using `awk`, do this with `awk` rather than in a shell loop (calling `awk` in a loop like that is slow and unnecessary):

```
awk 'FNR == 2 { 
    printf "python2 script.py %s 1 5.732436 %s f%s n\n", FILENAME, $1, FILENAME
}' *.b
```

This calls `awk` with all of your `.b` files as input.  For line two of each file, it will print the desired output to standard output, taking the data from the first field of the current input file.

`FILENAME` is a special variable in `awk` that contains the name of the current input file.  Likewise, `FNR` is the current record number (line number) within the current file.

If you're using GNU `awk` (likely on a Linux system) and your files are very big, you could speed things up a  bit by calling `nextfile` after printing. This would skip to the next input file immediately, without reading more from the current file.

```
awk 'FNR == 2 { 
    printf "python2 script.py %s 1 5.732436 %s f%s n\n", FILENAME, $1, FILENAME
    nextfile
}' *.b
```

`nextfile` is also supported by `mawk`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
awk 'FNR==2 {print ("python2 script.py " FILENAME " 1 5.732436 " $1 " f" FILENAME " n")}' *.b
```