# Cycle in bash - syntax

Tags: bash, rename

What is wrong here?

```
for file in ffn* do;
rename 's/ffn//' ffn*; 
done
```

There is an error in syntax.

Comment: rename deals with multiple files itself. Why would you need the for loop?

Comment: Also, the ; goes before the do, not after.

Comment: And $file is being used where?

Comment: It would have been no harm to read 'man bash' or 'help for' from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon is in the wrong place. Try:

```
for file in ffn*; do
    rename 's/ffn//' "$file"
done
```

or, because `rename` can take many files at once, try:

```
rename 's/ffn//' ffn*
```

Comment: Thank you very much